# json module install error i was use windows 10 pro 64 bit, pls give solutions rectify this issue

Tags: python

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install jsonlib
Collecting jsonlib
  Using cached jsonlib-1.6.1.tar.gz (43 kB)
Installing collected packages: jsonlib
    Running setup.py install for jsonlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Mageshkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dz8cos59\jsonlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Mageshkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dz8cos59\jsonlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Mageshkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7a5omup8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\jsonlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Mageshkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dz8cos59\jsonlib\
    Complete output (41 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying jsonlib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_jsonlib' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_jsonlib.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release_jsonlib.obj
    _jsonlib.c
    _jsonlib.c(99): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
    c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\unicodeobject.h(177): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_GetSize'
    _jsonlib.c(450): warning C4996: 'PyLong_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
    c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\longobject.h(106): note: see declaration of 'PyLong_FromUnicode'
    _jsonlib.c(550): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    _jsonlib.c(643): warning C4020: 'PyFloat_FromString': too many actual parameters
    _jsonlib.c(655): warning C4996: 'PyLong_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
    c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\longobject.h(106): note: see declaration of 'PyLong_FromUnicode'
    _jsonlib.c(1186): warning C4013: 'PyString_CheckExact' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    _jsonlib.c(1188): warning C4013: 'PyString_Check' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    _jsonlib.c(1208): warning C4013: 'PyObject_Unicode' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    _jsonlib.c(1208): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    _jsonlib.c(1406): warning C4013: 'PyInt_CheckExact' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    _jsonlib.c(1517): warning C4013: 'PyString_AS_STRING' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    _jsonlib.c(1517): warning C4047: 'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    _jsonlib.c(1517): warning C4024: 'ascii_constant': different types for formal and actual parameter 1
    _jsonlib.c(1539): warning C4013: 'PyInt_Check' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    _jsonlib.c(1931): warning C4047: '=': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    _jsonlib.c(1970): warning C4047: 'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    _jsonlib.c(1970): warning C4024: 'serializer_append_ascii': different types for formal and actual parameter 2
    _jsonlib.c(2089): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_Encode': deprecated in 3.3
    c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(791): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_Encode'
    _jsonlib.c(2123): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_Encode': deprecated in 3.3
    c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(791): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_Encode'
    _jsonlib.c(2161): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule3' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__jsonlib build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release_jsonlib.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8_jsonlib.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release_jsonlib.cp38-win_amd64.lib
    LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit__jsonlib
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release_jsonlib.cp38-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Mageshkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dz8cos59\jsonlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Mageshkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dz8cos59\jsonlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Mageshkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7a5omup8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\jsonlib' Check the logs for full command output.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What have you done? You should consider making some effort to be helped in return.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed python 3+ Version on your system.

"pip install jsonlib" is for lower versions of python that is why you're getting the
linker error

Try using "pip install jsonlib-python3" in the command prompt in administrator mode as it is for higher versions of python

This did the work for me ...Hope it helps :)

---

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>pip install jsonlib-python3 Requirement already satisfied: jsonlib-python3 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\p rograms\python\python38\lib\site-packages (1.6.1)

C:\Windows\system32>python Python 3.8.2 (tag s/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64bit(AM D64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> json.__version__ '2.0.9'
>>>
```